# tornado - What should I do to execute RequestHandler.write and then sleep for a second while the written content stays visible?

Tags: web, tornado

```
    try:
        username = self.get_argument('username')
    except:
        self.write('Username empty')
        time.sleep(1)
        self.redirect('/auth/login')
```

I want `Username empty` to be visible for one second and then redirect. But nothing seems to appear on the page before redirection. I know it's because nothing will be shown to the client before connection is closed. So anyway to display the written content for a second?

Comment: Not really related to your question, but you shouldn't use time.sleep() in tornado. Calling it will lock up your server for the sleep time. Instead yield tornado.gen.sleep()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `self.redirect`, that sends a header, which causes the browser to immediately redirect to /auth/login. This is how HTTP redirects work, nothing to do with Tornado.

If you want the page to remain visible, you can serve a page using [meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) with a delay in place of `self.write('Username empty')`:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL='http://example.com/auth/login'">
```

But meta refresh isn't really ideal either — the W3C has discouraged its used for a long time. What I would do in this situation is redirect immediately and show the error on the login page. For example:

```
self.redirect('/auth/login?error=%s' % tornado.escape.url_escape('Username empty'))
```

then show the error argument on the login page if it is set. So, in the handler:

```
...
error = self.get_argument('error', None)
if error is not None:
    error = tornado.escape.url_unescape(error)
....
self.render('foo.html', error=error)
```

in the template:

```
{% if error %}
{{ error }}
{% end %}
```